# FFMPEG Multiply blend results in green output

Tags: video, ffmpeg, colors

Using a simple overlay the colors are correct, but when I use a blending mode then the color of the output is either green (for multiply) or pink (for addition)

```
ffmpeg -i test-video.mp4  -i outro-frames/Outro.%05d.png -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref[scaled][ref];[ref][scaled]blend=all_mode=multiply[m];[m][0]overlay=x=0:y=0" test-video-outro.mp4
```

Frame from input PNG sequence

[image: Input frame]

Frame after using multiply blending mode

[image: Output frame]

Thanks to the suggestion from Gyan the color issue is partly resolved by adding `format=gbrp` to the filterchain.

Instead of the green tint the animation now starts inversed with a solid black background then flips after a few frames to the correct colors.

The first few frames render incorrectly

[image: First few frames almost black]

Then they switch and become as I’d like them to be

[image: Then they render correctly]

Comment: Convert the video to a RGB pixel format using `format=gbrp` before feeding it to blend. At present, blend is acting upon a YUV input.

Comment: Thanks very much Gyan, this definitely resolves the green issue, but there is still a problem with the rendering, I’ve updated the question to show how it looks. If you have any idea why this is happening I’d appreciate it. I also get this warning message now `No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to gbrp.` which I’m not sure if I should be concerned about? Thanks again.